# why gc of swt does not draw any image in Mac os mojave with new SWT?

Tags: macos, swt, macos-mojave

Hi I am working on an application where we take screenshot and display the image by painting it through gc. After upgrading to macos mojave the same code does not work.I had depicted the same in below snipets .Here in paint listiner instead of taking the gc from paint event I am creating another gc on which I am doing some operation and through that gc I am drawing the image .This solution works in windows and mac os  up to high siera (10.13).With Mojave update creating another gc gives an white image and when i directly try drawing using the gc from paint event it works without much issue.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.window.Window;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.PaletteData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ScreenShotWithGC {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Capture");
    Button save = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    save.setText("save");

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
      public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        /* Take the screen shot */
        GC gc = new GC(display);
        final Image image = new Image(display, display.getBounds());
        gc.copyArea(image, 0, 0);
        gc.dispose();
ImageData imageData = image.getImageData();
image.dispose();
        Image imagetemp=new Image(display, imageData);
        Shell popup = new Shell(shell, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
        popup.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        popup.setText("Image");
        popup.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);
        popup.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
          public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            image.dispose();
          }
        });

        ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(popup, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(sc, SWT.NONE);
        sc.setContent(canvas);
        canvas.setBounds(display.getBounds());
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
          public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
              GC gc=e.gc;
                PaletteData offscreenImagePalette = new PaletteData(0x0000FF00, 0x00FF0000, 0xFF000000);
                ImageData offscreenImageData = new ImageData(1000, 768, 32, offscreenImagePalette);
                offscreenImageData.type = SWT.BITMAP;
            Image   gdim = new Image(null, offscreenImageData);
            GC  ggc = new GC(gdim, Window.getDefaultOrientation());
                //gc=ggc;
                gc.fillRectangle(0, 0, 1000, 768);

                gc.drawImage(imagetemp, 0, 0);

                if(gc==ggc)
                {
                    e.gc.drawImage(gdim, 0, 0);
                }
          }
        });
        popup.open();
        save.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ImageLoader saver = new ImageLoader();
                saver.data = new ImageData[] { imageData };
                saver.save("/Users/prabhu_n/Desktop/Image/output.png", SWT.IMAGE_PNG);
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

      }
    });
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Any clue on this will be helpful
**Update**:This code works with older swt but with new version of swt the getimagedata() does not return proper value.

Comment: Probably Eclipse bug [538487](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538487)

Comment: Thanks the Image data seems to be wrong here And we cannot create the orginal image from the imagedata returned by the call of getimagedata()